# Primefaces popup dialog not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a jsf page having a popup button that opens a following dialog popup:

```
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Select different user"
        widgetVar="dlg" appendToBody="true">

    <h:form id="form23">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
            <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" 
                id="username" required="true" label="username" />

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
            <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" 
                id="password" required="true" label="password" />

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" />
            </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:form>
```

But instead of opening as popup it is getting displayed outside the page itself. the dialog is outside the main form. Help!!

---

I tried that but still the same problem persists..below is my modified code..

```
<h:form id="create-ticket">
    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Select different user" widgetVar="dlg" appendToBody="true">

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
        <p:inputText value="#{loginBean.username}" 
                id="username" required="true" label="username" />

        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" 
                id="password" required="true" label="password" />

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" 
                />
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>

 </p:dialog>
     <h:panelGroup>
     <h:outputLabel value="#{I18N['Create_Ticket_for_other_users']}" styleClass="atf-header"></h:outputLabel>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="search_section" layout="block"
       styleClass="atf-content-area atf-separarot-botton">   <!-- This is the section where we get the grey background -->
         <h:panelGroup id="input_search_section" styleClass="">
            <h:outputText id="name" value="Siddharth Mishra"    
            labelStyleClass="atf-label">
            </h:outputText>
        </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="atf-right atf-inline-block">
        <p:commandButton id="btn_search" value="select different user"
            styleClass="atf-button-search" onclick="dlg.show();" type="button"
            >

        </p:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:panelGroup>
```

Now i only have one form you can see the popup dialog section + the button which is calling the popup under h:panelgroup.Atached is the image how the form currently looks Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: In case you need help **restructure your code** and be **explicitly clear** about what your problem is, what you have tried so far and what you would like to achieve. Delete your 'answer' and edit your question instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to restructure your code.

*Don't nest forms inside other forms.

*You dont have  the end-tag of your p:dialog.

```
<h:form>    
    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Select different user"
            widgetVar="dlg" appendToBody="true">

          //Content ex inputtext

    </p:dialog>

<p:commandButton value="Show Dialog" onclick="dlg.show();" type="button" />  
</h:form>
```